# How to get used http call parameter in AngularJs promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to log if there is no data in some returned Javascript object. Since http calls are asynchronous, my implementation doesn't work. I'm checking if the object is empty and if it is, I would like to log it's id. How could I get the right scenarioId to my else statement?

```
for (var i in $scope.scenarioData){
                var scenarioId = $scope.scenarioData[i].id;                
                dataService.getResultsByScenarioId(scenarioId).then(function(response){
                    if (Object.keys(response.data).length != 0){                    
                        //This is not interesting in this context
                    }
                    else{
                        //I would like to log the called scenarioId here
                        $log.info("No data in scenarioId: " + scenarioId);
                    }
                });
        }
```

This is the used service

```
ptraApp.service('dataService', function($http) {
    this.getResultsByScenarioId = function(id) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/ptra/resultArchive/' + id,
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the function that call to servive to external function
for example:

```
for (var i in $scope.scenarioData){
      var scenarioId = $scope.scenarioData[i].id;
      getResult(scenarioId)
}

function getResult(scenarioId){
    dataService.getResultsByScenarioId(scenarioId).then(function(response){
                if (Object.keys(response.data).length != 0){                    
                    //This is not interesting in this context
                }
                else{
                    //I would like to log the called scenarioId here
                    $log.info("No data in scenarioId: " + scenarioId);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed! Feeling pretty stupid that I couldn't figure out this solution...

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like that snippet:

```
ptraApp.service('dataService', function($http) {
        this.getResultsByScenarioId = function(id) {

    return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/ptra/resultArchive/' + id}).
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // ...
   );
}});
```